# How to order, group, order with mySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Here is a simplified version of my table

```
tbl_records
-title
-created
-views
```

I am wondering how I can make a query where they are grouped by title, but the record that is returned for each group is the most recently created. I then will order it by views.

One way I guess is to do a sub query and order it by created and then group it by title and then from those results order it by views. I guess there is a better way though.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
-title: Gnu Design
-created: 2009-11-11 14:47:18
-views: 104

-title: Gnu Design
-created:2010-01-01 21:37:09
-views:9

-title: French Connection
-created:2010-05-01 09:27:19
-views:20
```

I would like the results to be:

```
-title: French Connection
-created:2010-05-01 09:27:19
-views:20

-title: Gnu Design
-created:2010-01-01 21:37:09
-views:9
```

Only the most recent Gnu Design is shown and then the results are ordered by views.

Comment: If you have sample data, it would be a lot clearer.

Comment: Yes, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of the `greatest-n-per-group` problem that appears frequently on StackOverflow.

Here's my usual solution:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_records t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_records t2 ON (t1.title = t2.title AND 
  (t1.created < t2.created OR t1.created = t2.created AND t1.primarykey < t2.primarykey))
WHERE t2.title IS NULL;
```

Explanation: find the row `t1` for which no other row `t2` exists with the same `title` and a greater `created` date.  In case of ties, use some unique key to resolve the tie, unless it's okay to get multiple rows per `title`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select i.*, o.views from
   (
       select
       title
       , max(created) as last_created
       from tbl_records
       group by title
   ) i inner join tbl_records o
   on i.title = o.title and i.last_created = o.created
   order by o.views desc
```

I'm assuming that the aggregation to be applied to `views` is `count()`, but could well be wrong (you'll need to have some way of defining which measure of views you wish to have for the lastest created title). Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: have seen your sample data and edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, 
       MAX(created), 
       views 
FROM table 
GROUP BY title 
ORDER BY views DESC
```